# Clicking does not work in Jupyterlab [OS X, chrome]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**Bug description:**

1. No response when clicking any buttons except files.
2. When I want to leave one cell to another,  weird jumping back happens.

The demo below is more explanatory.

**To Reproduce:**
On my mac, basically after opening Jupyterlab, all clicks inside give no responses.

**Expected behavior:**
A normal and smooth experience like before.

**Screenshots:**
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8DJO.jpg)

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**

- OS: [OSX 10.14.3]
- Browser [chrome 72.0.3626.119]
- JupyterLab [0.35.3]

**Additional context:**
Jupyterlab worked well one week ago on my OS X 10.11 El Capitan. And then I  want to add a plugin (@lckr/jupyterlab_variableinspector). So I need to upgrade my node, npm and thus my OS X. After upgrading them and install the plugin, the problem happens. But I am not sure it is because of the version, because I did not use Jupyterlab in this week and may do something else to my system. I tried to disable the plugin and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was caused by a Chrome plugin with similar functions like "RightToCopy". I just deleted it and reinstalled the Chrome, then everything works well.